# Help me understand the formal logic notation?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm trying to describe the predicate/proposition
**n>1**
in formal logic notation.

Apparently the answer is

> ∃y. y=1 $\land$ n>y.

If I try to read this, it reads:

> There exists a y. y is 1 AND n is greater than y

I can't quite put my finger on it but there just seems to me something wrong with this solution...
The answer describes y and its property and somehow suddenly the whole thing is also just **n>1**.

I guess I need some kind of a metaphor to understand this way of converting to formal logic notation smoothly.

I also wonder if others struggle with this too.

Forgot to add this info. To clarify the confusion:

> y = 1 has been defined as $\forall$x. x*y = x
>   but y>1 is not defined.
>   x>y is defined.

For detailed problem description and solution, click [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2005/assignments/ps1sol.pdf) and look **Problem 3 (b)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Express each of the following predicates and propositions in formal logic notation. The domain of discourse is the nonnegative integers, $\Bbb N$.
>
> In addition to the propositional operators, variables and quantiﬁers, you may deﬁne predicates using addition, multiplication, and equality symbols, but *no constants* (like 0, 1, . . . ).
>
> **(b)** x > 1.
>
> **Solution.** The straightforward approach is to deﬁne x = 1 as ∀ y. xy = y and then express x > 1 as ∃ y. (y = 1) ∧ (x > y).

There is no symbol $1$ in the language. That means we need to come up with a symbol to represent it.

After defining the property "is equal to $1$" by the formula with one free variable $(\forall x)(x \times \cdot =x)$, we can only ever refer to $1$ by this formula. So we make a shorthand for it: the literal string "$z\  \underline{=1}$" is defined to be shorthand for $(\forall x)(x \times z = x)$, whatever $z$ is. I've used an underline to emphasise that this is not an expression in the original language, but a shorthand to be expanded.

Finally, to express $n>1$ without using the forbidden symbol $1$, it's enough to define $1$, assert that it exists at all, and then say that $n$ is bigger than it:

$$(\exists y)(y\ \underline{=1} \wedge n>y)$$

See also the solution to (a) as to how you define "greater than".

Comment: n>1 is not in the language. Only n=1

Comment: I edited my original post to include additional information to clarify the confusion.